# How to use Linq to group every N number of rows

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I cannot find a way to make this work and hoping someone has an idea.  A simplified example would be having a list of say integers 1-100, i want to group every 3 rows so the result would be 1,2,3 in first group then 4,5,6 in next group etc.  I know how to get every nth record but what I need is all the records so I can then aggregate them, using first, last, sum, max, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split List into Sublists with LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419019/split-list-into-sublists-with-linq)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
var q = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).GroupBy(x => x/3);
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Being pedantic - Enumerable.Range(1, 100) since he wanted to start at 1.

Comment: If the first number is 0, it works fine. But if the first number is 1, the first group has one less element. For example {0,1,2}, {3,4,5}, but {1,2}, {3,4,5}. How to fix this?

Answer (score 45):

This example should work for querying non-numeric collections.  It projects an index into the object to be grouped, and then removes it again during the grouping.

```
var studentQuery2 = students
    .Select((student, index) => new {student, index})
    .GroupBy(g => g.index / 3, i => i.student);
```

Comment: Thanks also, but where does index come from?

Comment: i was hoping the select would project its index into the query.  Looks like it doesn't.  I'll update the example accordingly - so that you can use it with non-int based collections.

Comment: FYI, in the next version of the framework there will be a "zip join" extension method. If you zip a query result with an infinite sequence of integers, you get an indexed sequence. See my recent blog article on this subject for details.

Comment: nice - i'll definitely be looking forward to that feature.

Comment: @eric - thanks, im gonna try that out. Is that faster than using the select with index into a new type?

Answer (score 2):

How about a simpler approach:

```
var index = 0;
var grpOf3s = students.GroupBy(x => index++ / 3);
```

**Update:**
If you are using the `Key` value of the group item then you will need to convert the group enumerable to a list. Otherwise you will get a different `Key` every time it is accessed.

```
var index = 0;
var grpOf3s = students.GroupBy(x => index++ / 3).ToList();
```